# vue-strap alert component takes up space even when hidden

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-strap

I am using `wffranco/vue-strap` alerts in a Vue 2.5.16 component:

```
<accordion :one-at-atime="true" type="info">
    <panel type="primary" :header="'Week ' + cycle.week + ': ' + cycle.name" v-for="(cycle, index) in cycles" :key="cycle.id">
        <alert :type="alerts[cycle.id] ? alerts[cycle.id].type : 'error'" v-if="alerts[cycle.id] !== null">
            {{ alerts[cycle.id] ? alerts[cycle.id].msg : '' }}
        </alert>
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="update">
            <label :for="'location_' + cycle.id">Location</label>
            ....various other elements...
        </form>
    </panel>
</accordion>
```

Even tho `v-if="alerts[cycle.id] !== null"` hides the alert, it still takes up vertical space in page as shown below (I've highlighted the space using the Vue JS Chrome dev extension):

[image]

How do I prevent the alert from taking up that vertical space?

Comment: Can you post a runnable snippet reproducing this error? We could then better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but you can always add a wrapper around to hide it. `<template>` can be used as empty wrapper.

```
...
<template v-if="alerts[cycle.id] !== null">
        <alert ...>
            ...
        </alert>
</template>
...
```